# Yii syntax for PGSQL date INTERVAL function

Tags: postgresql, yii, sql-date-functions

I am locked with how to fill the following code

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('esdate', 'now()-interval \'1 day\'', false, 'AND', '>');
```

if I use 'now()' alone it could work but as soon as I add the interval function I cannot get it done. I guess the escaped quote may not be accepted, but was unable to find any correct syntax.

Any help more than appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$criteria->addCondition( "esdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY" );
```

Comment: great ! But still need the quote...
    $criteria->addCondition( "esdate > now() - interval '1 day'" );